# How to sum multiple integers read from the console in Java?

Tags: java

I need the user to enter some numbers and the program will sum them until the last one is smaller then the previous. Something like this:

```
Next:1
Next:3
Next:6
Next:1
Result:10
```

So far I only made two numbers sum with each other, but not with the rest of the numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number, number2, result;
    result = 0;
    System.out.print("Next: ");
    number2 = scan.nextInt();
    while ((number=scan.nextInt()) > number2){
        result = number + number2;
        number2 = number;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: above loop:
result += number2;
Inside loop:
result += number;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+=` to make things easier. Also, give your variables better names.

```
//store last input, current input, and the sum
int last = 0;
int result = 0;
int input = 0;
//note that if you enter invalid input, this will go into an infinite loop
while ((input = scan.nextInt()) > last){
    result += input; //directly adds the input to the sum
    last = input;
}
System.out.println("Sum: " + result);
```

To prevent the infinite loop thing, you should use a `try`-`catch` block to detect invalid input and `scan.next()` to clear the invalid data, like so:

```
while (input > last){
    try{
        input = scan.nextInt();
        result += input;
        last = input;
    }catch (InputMismatchException e){
        System.err.println("Invalid input"); //you could also use .out
        scan.next(); //eliminate invalid data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that solves my problem + the try catch bonus :)

Answer (score 2):

On this line, you keep overwriting your previous results:

```
result = number + number2;
```

Try changing it to:

```
result += number;
```

Also add the following assignment before your while loop:

```
result = number2;
```

Comment: You'll miss the initial number provided

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number, number2, result;
    number2 = scan.nextInt();
    result = number2;
    while ((number=scan.nextInt())>number2){
        result += number;
        number2=number;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    scan.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `result += number`. This adds `number` to `result`.

Note that `number = scan.nextInt()` is an assignment within a conditional expression. They are not to everyone's taste. In fact, you have a bug in your code (the first number is not included in the sum), so you need to refactor anyway: initialising with `int result = number2 = scan.nextInt();` is one way.

Comment: You'll miss the initial number provided

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
number2 = 0;
number = scan.nextInt();
while (number > number2) {
    result += number;
    number2 = number;
    number = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class SumIt {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number, number2, result;
    result = 0;
    System.out.print("Next: ");
    number2 = scan.nextInt();
    result += number2;
    while ((number=scan.nextInt()) > number2){
        result += number;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you erase the  result each time, try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number, number2, result;
    System.out.print("Next: ");
    result = scan.nextInt();
    number = result;
    while ((number2=scan.nextInt()) > number){
        result += number2;
        number = number2;
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
System.out.println( "Enter a number: " )
number = scan.nextInt();
result = number;
do {
    System.out.println( "Enter a number: " )
    number2 = scan.nextInt();
    result += number2;
    number = number2;
} while ( number2 >= number );
```